# What is the performance overhead of JavaScript's typeof (edit: in V8)?

Tags: javascript, performance

In our JS codebase, we use Flow for static type-checks. Unfortunately our server endpoints aren't very consistent with their response structures, so our static types often fail us there. We're thinking about switching to a runtime-check strategy, but I'm worried about the overhead. Responses are sometimes on the order of thousands of objects.

Is `typeof` (and `Array.isArray()`, now that I think about it) as cheap as it seems like it should be (a binary flag check or something)?

Comment: It depends on the JS engine.

Comment: Set a concrete and testable performance goal (e.g. 20ms max to process AJAX result), then write your code. If you meet the goal, don't optimize. You're done. If you _don't_ meet the goal, profile your code and find the bottleneck. 99% sure `typeof` will not be it. My point is, you don't have any code yet, so this is the wrong time to be asking about optimization.

Comment: I'm asking more for a general overview of how typeof works under the hood, from someone who knows about that. Not an authoritative yes/no.

Comment: `typeof` is pretty cheap. Everything’s cheap compared to doing the wrong thing, though.